# Matrix multiplication causes "non-conformable" error when called from `optim`

Tags: r, optimization

i am trying to run a simple optimization problem and i always get the 'non-conformable arguments' error. However the error occurs only within optim, so i am at the end of my understanding. Here is my code:

```
f <- function(W, x, y){
  temp <- W %*% x
  temp1 <- t(temp) %*% temp
  temp2 <- t(temp) %*% y
  temp3 <- t(y) %*% y
  (temp1 - 2 * temp2 + temp3)[1]
}

x <- matrix(c(1,2), ncol=1)
y <- matrix(c(5,3), ncol=1)
W <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4), ncol=2)
f(W,x=x,y=y)
> 53
```

so far so good. The function works just fine. However once i put the values into optim:

```
optim(par=W, fn=f, x=x, y=y)
```

i get:

```
> Error in W %*% x : non-conformable arguments
```

how can i fix this?

Comment: If you add `print(W)` at start of `f` you would see that `W` is used as vector (when using `optim`). You should transform `W` to matrix with adequate dimensions at start of `f`.

Comment: wow, merci. yes that was it. can you post this as an answer, then you can get some points for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `print(W)` at start of `f` you would see that `W` is used as vector (it seems that `optim` converts `par` to vector). You should transform `W` to matrix with adequate dimensions at start of `f`.